# Can I update a block in a running journey/trigger?

Tags: trigger, journeybuilder, content-builder

Am I able to update a content block that is called on using contentBlockByID("#") without pausing the journey or trigger? Will the changes be reflected without pausing it?

Answer (score 0):

Anything inside of a Journey or Trigger is pre-processed once it is published, this includes content block calls (whether AMPscript or dynamic content block, etc.).  The only exception to this is for calls that require data from an outside source. So for instance if you have a lookup to get the contentblockid from a data extension, that will not be 'snapshot' and will pull the most recent iteration, but this also increases the amount of processing needed to get the email out and can slow down your send times.

So long story short, the answer is the changes in a content block used in a live triggered send will not be reflected in the sends unless you are calling the content block using data from an outside source. Otherwise you would have to pause republish and restart to see the changes.

e.g.

```
%%[
  SET @content = Lookup(@myDE,"ContentID","SubKey",@Subkey)
]%%
  %%=ContentBlockByID(@content)=%%
```